# Python Tkinter : rectangle disappears but I don't want to

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a snake game in `Python 3` using `Tkinter`. Everything works except that *sometimes my apple (a red rectangle) disappears before the snake eats it*. I tried to monitor the delete method with a `print` but it seems that it does work correctly...

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from random import randint


class Snake(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.WIDTH = 600
        self.HEIGHT = 600

def init(self):
    self.kp = [(30,0),(30,0),(30,0),(30,0)]
    self.vx = 30
    self.vy = 0
    self.x , self.y = 300 , 300
    self.taille = 30
    self.queue = 1
    self.nb = 1
    self.pos = [(300,300)]

def init_graph(self):
    self.cnv = Canvas(self,width = self.WIDTH, height = self.HEIGHT , bg = 'white')
    self.cnv.pack()
    self.cnv.create_rectangle(self.x , self.y ,self.x+ self.taille ,self.y + self.taille , fill = 'black',tag='1')
    self.new_pomme()
    self.score()


def new_pomme(self):
    self.pomme = [randint(0,19)*30,randint(0,19)*30]
    self.cnv.create_rectangle(self.pomme[0],self.pomme[1],self.pomme[0] + self.taille,self.pomme[1] + self.taille, fill = 'red',tag = 'pomme') 


def maj(self):
    self.kp.append((self.vx,self.vy))
    self.nb += 1
    if [self.x,self.y] == self.pomme:   
        print("Pomme ! ",self.pomme)             
        self.cnv.delete('pomme')
        self.new_pomme()            
        self.queue += 1
        self.text.destroy()
        self.score()
    else:

        self.cnv.delete(str(self.nb-self.queue))
        del self.pos[0]

    self.x += self.vx           
    self.y += self.vy
    if  (self.x,self.y) in self.pos:
        self.perdu()
    else:
        self.pos.append((self.x,self.y))


    self.cnv.create_rectangle(self.x , self.y ,self.x+ self.taille ,self.y + self.taille , fill = 'black', tag =str(self.nb))
    print(round(time.clock(),2))

    if self.kp[-1] == self.kp[-2]:
        if len(self.kp) > 10:
            for i in range(5):
                del self.kp[i]
        self.after(500,self.maj)




def bouger(self):
    self.bind("<Up>", self.haut) 
    self.bind("<Down>", self.bas)
    self.bind("<Left>", self.gauche)
    self.bind("<Right>", self.droite)
    self.mainloop()

def haut(self,event):
    self.vy = -30
    self.vx = 0
    self.maj()

def bas(self,event):
    self.vy = 30
    self.vx = 0
    self.maj()

def gauche(self,event):
    self.vy = 0
    self.vx = -30
    self.maj()

def droite(self,event):
    self.vy = 0
    self.vx = 30
    self.maj()

    def perdu(self):
        print("Perdu !")
        self.text_perdu = Label(self,text='Perdu ! Score final : ' + str(self.queue-1))
        self.text_perdu.pack(side = TOP)
        Button(self,text='Recommencer',command=jeu()).pack(side = BOTTOM)


    def score(self):
        self.text = Label(self,text='Score : ' +str(self.queue-1))
        self.text.pack(side = BOTTOM)


def jeu():
    snake = Snake()
    snake.init()
    snake.init_graph()
    snake.bouger()
    snake.mainloop()

jeu()
```

> Please note: There are indentation mistakes from the copy/paste , all there is only one class and one fonction jeu() outside of that class. All the rest is inside the class

Comment: Problem solved : self.cnv.delete() delete tags AND ids.. So my rectangle tagged 'pomme' is deleted because it has also an id (often '2')

Answer (score 0):

Use "move" instead of destroying and creating an new one each time.  A simple example.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 260, 120, 360,
                    outline='white', fill='blue')
rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 10, 120, 110,
                    outline='white', fill='red')

y = x = 5
for ctr in range(50):
    time.sleep(0.025)
    canvas.move(rc1, x, -y)
    canvas.move(rc2, x, y)
    canvas.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay , thanks  i will try ! Is there a particular reason why I should use "move" instead of deleting/creating ?